# Using third party React Components with Fable/Elmish

Tags: reactjs, f#, fable-f#, elmish, carbon-design-system

I'm trying to integrate [Carbon Design System - React SDK](https://react.carbondesignsystem.com/) in a Fable/Elmish application and it looks like I have to create the [property type definitions](https://gist.github.com/matias-quezada/93f83f4190998134ca7dd8842177331e#file-client-fs-L16-L66) (some of them I just guessed) for every component in order to use it.

The component already [has TypeScript definitions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/carbon-components-react) in.

---

Do I really have to manually create type definitions for every React component I want to try or use?

Is there a simple or automatic way to use a React component from F# code without having to write the property type definitions for every component I want to try?

How do people in the F# community use the components from the React ecosystem?

---

I've tried [ts2fable](https://github.com/fable-compiler/ts2fable) but it generates invalid unreliable code: [Example](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/44360321/89631323-ed8c8e00-d8a0-11ea-9aa6-e0af22a2e9ca.png) where most lines have error, I've also transpiled dependencies (`typings/shared.d.ts` and React type definitions)

I'm also looking at [TypeProviders](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.TypeProviders.SDK) but not sure if this can be a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 3):

> Do I really have to manually create type definitions for every React component I want to try or use?

You do not have to create type definitions. Instead, you can write F# code that is not type-safe using the dynamic module provided by Fable.

> Is there a simple or automatic way to use a React component from F# code without having to write the property type definitions for every component I want to try?

Currently there is the (imperfect) ts2fable tool, or you can write untyped F# code, taking care that the output will have the correct "shape" in JavaScript.

> How do people in the F# community use the components from the React ecosystem?

Some common libraries have F# bindings that are available on Nuget. Otherwise you will need to write some bindings yourself, perhaps using ts2fable.

This is definitely a pain-point with Fable at the moment.

---

For example, say the JavaScript library expects a props object like this:

```js
{
  foo: 1,
  bar: [ "a", "b", "c" ],
  qux: "hello"
}
```

Then we can create this in Fable like so:

```ml
open Fable
open Fable.Core
open Fable.Core.JsInterop

let props = 
  createObj [
    "foo" ==> 1
    "bar" ==> ResizeArray<_>([ "a"; "b"; "c" ])
    "qux" ==> "hello"
  ]
```

Compiles to...

```js
export const props = {
    foo: 1,
    bar: ["a", "b", "c"],
    qux: "hello",
};
```

The F# type of `props` is `obj`.

The `==>` operator is just for convenience. You could also write:

```ml
open Fable
open Fable.Core
open Fable.Core.JsInterop

let props = 
  createObj [
    "foo", box 1
    "bar", box (ResizeArray<_>([ "a"; "b"; "c" ]))
    "qux", box "hello"
  ]
```

This is great for trying things out. However, you will be missing out on some the strongly-typed benefits of F#! Whether or not this trade-off is worth it will depend on your use-case.

---

In theory, a Type Provider could be written that takes an NPM module name and returns an appropriate F# type, perhaps leveraging ts2fable. This would be very powerful, but I don't think anyone has implemented this yet.